# Javas Math.sin() produces NaN all the time

Tags: java, math, double, nan

Forgive me if this is a dumb beginners problem, but I really don't get it.

I have a member variable declared like so:

```
public Double Value;
```

When I assign 3.14159265 to Value and try to compute the sine of it, this happens:

```
system.out.println(Value.toString()); //outputs 3.14159265
Value = Math.sin(Value);
system.out.println(Value.toString()); //outputs NaN
```

In fact, this happens with every single value I tried - even with 0!
Math.sin() seems to always produce NaN as a result, regardless of the arguments value.

The docs say:

> If the argument is NaN or an infinity, then the result is NaN.

But my argument is clearly not NaN or infinity!

What the heck is happening there?

***UPDATE***

Turns out I'm the dumbest programmer on earth. In my project the whole code is of course much more complex than the example above. It's kind of an expression parser & evaluator and for the defined mathematical functions I use a switch-clause to decide which function to call - **I forgot the break statement in the cases** which caused the sqrt function to be executed with a negative parameter.

As I said - dumbest programmer on earth...

I accepted the topmost answer as it is the best imho. Sorry guys for wasting your time -.-

Comment: Have you tried hardcoded doubles 0.0, 1.0?

Comment: Could be something with autoboxing... Could you try the same with a `double` value instead of `Double`?

Comment: your code doesn't even compile.. and how are you assigning the value?

Comment: How about a complete, minimal program that exhibits that behavior?

Comment: did you try to not do it with Double but with double to make sure it is not a autoboxing issue (which I don't seem to see one in your code though). If Math.sin(3.159) returns NaN then I would be troubled.

Comment: How do you assign a value to Value? I tried 'Value = 3.0d' and it worked for me.

Comment: Now that you say it, auto boxing might be an issue here. I'll try using double instead of Double.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Double value = 3.14159265;
System.out.println(value.toString()); //outputs 3.14159265
value = Math.sin(value);
System.out.println(value.toString()); //outputs NaN
```

outputs (as expected):

```
3.14159265
3.5897930298416118E-9
```

so problem should be somewhere else, which version of JDK are you using? is it 32 bit or 64 bit? is there other code in the middle that you didn't paste?

The only way to obtain a `NaN` from `Math.sin` is by using `inf` o `NaN` as the parameter. And without explicitly assign that value to a number you can obtain in just by doing wrong calculations, eg:

```
Double d = 0.0/0.0;
System.out.println(Math.sin(d));
double d2 = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
System.out.println(Math.sin(d2));
```

this will output: `NaN` twice.

Two notes:

- don't use capitalized letters for variables (use `value`, not `Value`)
- when you need stings as parameters (or composed to other strings) you don't need to explicitly call `toString()`, you can do `System.out.println(value)`

Answer (score 5):

THis is what I get:

```
Double Value;
Value = 3.14159265 ;
System.out.println(Value.toString()); //outputs 3.14159265
Value = Math.sin(Value);
System.out.println(Value.toString()); //outputs 3.5897930298416118E-9
```

So there are 2 options:

1. The code you posted isn't the code you're using (I notice you have a lower case S on system, so this won't compile)
2. Something else is changing the value of Value to NaN before or after you do the Math.sin

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you're using the `Double` reference (wrapper) type, not the `double` primitive type - why? What is the code that you're actually using to initialize `Value` (which, BTW, should not start with an uppercase character based on common Java coding standards)? My guess is that you're just not initializing `Value` properly. Try starting with using a `double` (not a `Double`).